# Need an elegant proof for $(q-r)x+(r-p)y+(p-q)z=0$ with given premises

Tags: algebra-precalculus, alternative-proof, ratio

The question comes from [Higher Algebra by Hall and Knight](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402179650):

> If $$\frac{x}{q+r-p}=\frac{y}{r+p-q}=\frac{z}{p+q-r}$$
>   then shew that $(q-r)x+(r-p)y+(p-q)z=0$

I did solve this problem eventually, but I do not like the approach. Here is my take on this question:

We have
$$\frac{x}{q+r-p}=\frac{y}{r+p-q}=\frac{z}{p+q-r}$$
Reciprocating each term, we have
$$\frac{q+r-p}{x}=\frac{r+p-q}{y}=\frac{p+q-r}{z}$$
Taking the first two terms, we have
$$\frac{q+r-p}{x}=\frac{r+p-q}{y}$$
$$\implies (r-p)y+qy-rx-px+qx=0 \tag{1}$$
Similarly, from the second and third terms, we have
$$(p-q)z+rz-py-qy+ry=0\tag{2}$$
and from the first and third terms, we have
$$(q-r)x+px-qz-rz+pz=0\tag{3}$$

On adding these three equations $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, we achieve after some tedious manipulations:

$$2((q-r)x+(r-p)y+(p-q)z)=0$$
$$\implies (q-r)x+(r-p)y+(p-q)z=0$$

**Q.E.D.**

I am not quite content with this proof. It seems... inelegant. Is there a better approach? If so, what is it?

Comment: I doubt that there is a more elegant proof, since it seems unavoidable that you have to perform some manipulations of the fractions. Sorry for that, sun is not always shining ;)

Comment: @57Jimmy I'm quite comfortable with manipulating fractions; what I'm uncomfortable with is long and tedious calculations. These seem so dull and mechanical that I tend to lose my interest at times. :-/ (I've skipped the dull parts of the calculation in my question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$ t = \dfrac{x}{q+r-p} = \dfrac{y}{r+p-q} = \dfrac{z}{p+q-r} $$
we have 
  $$\eqalign{(q−r)x+(r−p)y+(p−q)z &= t \left((q-r)(q+r-p) + (r-p)(r+p-q) + (p-q)(p+q-r)\right)\cr
&= t(A - B)\cr} $$
where
$$ A = (q-r)(q+r) + (r-p)(r+p)+(p-q)(p+q) = q^2 - r^2 + r^2 - p^2 + p^2 - q^2 = 0$$
and 
$$B = (q-r) p + (r-p) q + (p-q) r = qp - rp + rq - pq + pr - qr = 0 $$

Comment: Ok, this does look nicer :)

Comment: And it's easily comprehensible as well. Amazing! I knew there was a simpler approach. :-)

Answer (score 1):

By the well known property of proportions $$\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}=\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}$$ we have

$$\frac{x}{q+r-p}=\frac{y}{r+p-q}=\frac{z}{p+q-r}= K\ne 0$$ We can do $$\frac{x}{q+r-p}=\frac{x(q-r)}{q^2-r^2-pq+pr}$$ and similarly for the other two fractions, then the summ of denominators is nul so we get
$$\frac{(q-r)x+(r-p)y+(p-q)z}{0}=K$$ Thus necessarily the numerator must be equal to $0$ because $K$ is not infinite.